# React image not rendering from Mongo Database and express

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, file-upload, multer

I have the image path in my backend mongodb but can't render it for some reason. For passing in file I am using multer.

this is one my refrence document for the mongoDB database. Looking at this looks Like I was able to hookup the image path in the database but can't seem to render it.

[_id:64a069c53efaa8786285da61
topic:"Java"
users:Array
isRequesting:false
image:"uploads\image\e65a613e-9d76-4777-a376-d85526cb24f3.jpeg"
__v:1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6gd5.png)

this is the react code that should render it :
session just refers to the prior database document

<img src={`http:localhost:5000/${session.image}`} alt={session.topic} className='session-image' />

It's pretty much saying http:localhost:5000/uploads\image\e65a613e-9d76-4777-a376-d85526cb24f3.jpeg is not a working route

I've also allowed the /uploads/images to be accessed to server images statically in a middleware
app.use('/uploads/images', express.static(path.join('uploads', 'image')));

and the images are added when the document is created so I don't think there's an issue with the multer code.

I tried different ways to render the images using several imports rather than img src{} but that didn't yield anything either

Comment: `images` vs `image` typo